# AMD's NVML counterpart (c++)

Tags: c++, gpu, nvml

I would like to know what library AMD has that mimics the NVML counterpart of nvidia. What I want is to get temperature, powerusage, etc. in c++.

Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

The AMD version is called [ROCm SMI Library](https://github.com/RadeonOpenCompute/rocm_smi_lib). It is currently being developed, and is available on github. It has most of the basic capabilities though.